# Setting ID on child properties with EFBulkInsert

Tags: performance, entity-framework, bulkinsert

So im using EFBulkInsert https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

The problem is I have child objects I need to set the ID of the inserted parent objects.

Previously after inserting the parents objects I've tried to rely on the context to return the id's and set them on the child objects - then use EFBulkInsert to insert the child objects - every now and then the context gets confused even after recreating the context and I get the wrong id on the child objects.

Does anyone have a good pattern / strategy for setting the parent id on the child object I should mention i'm doing this for a batch of 1000 parent objects. So I don't particularly want to get the id's from the database after SaveChanges for the parent object unless it's performant.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I have is to add two temporary columns, firtst to hold an original Id, and second to hold parentId. After bulk insert update proper columns. This method requires privilages to modify the table.

I had a similar problem when I couldn't modify database, so I set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and  `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` to false, but results were not very satisfied.